# Error when programming disabling of 2dcollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the program so that if a certain number of rings are collected in the level that the player is in, the portal's 2d collider will be enabled and the player can move on to the next level. I am currently stuck because my code has an error on line 9 that reads:

property or indexer "Collision2D.enabled" cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

```
public class RingPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider2D Portal;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D portal)
    {
        if (portal.gameObject.tag == "Portal")
        {
            portal.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error? What's ``Collider2D``? You need to give considerably more detail.

Also I suspect you need to use string equality: if ``tag`` is a string, use ``equals``.

Comment: Have you tried https://forum.unity.com/threads/problem-with-collider2d.442643/?

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable named `Portal`, and a method parameter named `portal`. You're accidentally using `portal` when trying to disable `Portal`.

```cs
public class RingPickup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Collider2D Portal;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D portal)
    {
        if (portal.gameObject.tag == "Portal")
        {
            //portal.enabled = false;  <-- incorrect, uses "portal"
            Portal.enabled = false;  //<-- correct,   uses "Portal"
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest renaming either the parameter or the variable to have clear, concise names.